# SSRS report with three "levels" and collapse functionality

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I've been at it for hours (if not days) now, but I just don't understand how to create something like the image below. I created this image manually (with Pixlr) to show what the result should look like. Does anyone know of a tutorial to create a SSRS report looking like this? Or is there someone who can tell me how to get the three levels needed for this report. The data is obviously fake, but it's the way to do it that I would like to know. Thanks a million. Vincent.

[image: SSRS example of how it should look]

Comment: If you're using, Visual Studio you have to build this manually as stated in the answer below. If you use Report Builder, you can simply use the Table Wizard and it will build this for you based on the columns you choose to group by. Then of course you can still use Visual Studio to continue working on it.

Comment: At the moment no access to Report Builder, but thanks for the tip. Will ask the it guys about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a stepped report. Here is a nice **[tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/create-a-stepped-report-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017)** from Microsoft.

You gonna end up with the categories (Groups in RS) that looks like this: 
[image: Row groups in Reporting Services]

Then the folding option (plus/minus sign) is a property you add on the groupings. For example the subcategory in the Row Groups pane, right click/Group Properties/ Visibility and then checkbox 'Display can be toggled by this report item' and choose the category (one level up)

[image: Folding functionality]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna take a look at the tutorial. I may have used some wrong dummy data, because in the real thing there are multiple measures (amount, count and average). If I don't succeed with the tutorial I'll post a better suitable example. But maybe the thing I want isn't even possible in one single tablix. To be continued... ;-)

Comment: Almost everything is possible :) Give it a shot! Ask if you don't succeed

Comment: @Pepsys I've succeeded with the use of both your example and the tutorial. Thanks a lot! :-)